# FabricJS flip issue with clone after serialize

Tags: canvas, serialization, fabricjs, flip

When i am changing flip of an object, all looks correct on the canvas, but when i am serializing canvas and seserializatio later it's taking wrong flip.
The way i am changing flip:

```
if(object) {
    if(type === 'flip-x'){
        (object.flipX ? object.set({ flipX: false }) : object.set({ flipX: true }));
    }else{
        (object.flipY ? object.set({ flipY: false }) : object.set({ flipY: true }));
    }
}
canvas.renderAll();
```

After that i am cloning the object with two different methods:

```
//1
var clonedObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, arr[i]);
//2
savingOptions=['id'];
arr[i].clone(function(clonedObj){
    // getting clonedObj
},savingOptions);
```

Both works, perhaps first need an improvement but on both after serializations cloned object lost his flipX and flipY no matter what i do. The serialization i am doing:

```
var data=JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject(savingOptions));
canvas.loadFromJSON(data,function(){
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Also i am checking `object.originalState` and it's all ok.